# Where do I put the php file so Firefox sees/runs it?

Tags: firefox, php

I am brand new to web services and php. I want to experiment writing php code/files. I have installed

- nginx 1.10
- php 7.0.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.1

I can get the php file to execute from the command line, but I cannot figure out what to do / how to get Firefox to find and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default public web root for a standard nginx installation should be located in **/usr/share/nginx/html**

Try to create a test script to see if php is properly running and setup by creating a new file called *test.php* and following content

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

save the file in your default web root and you should be able to run it by opening your standard browser and navigating to localhost/test.php

It should display a php-configuration page and you should be able to write your own code.

The easiest way to set it up locally, would be by installing a simple LAMP server (Apache, MySQL, PHP).

Read the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) for further information!

Comment: Ok, checking /etc/nginx/sites-available/default  I find root /var/www/html;
When I place test.php in that directory and point Firefox at localhost/test.php it finds it, but asks me if I want to download it; it does not execute it.
I need to stick with nginx.

Comment: Seems that your php module is not setup properly. Read the ubuntu wiki about nginx and see what packages are required and how to configure them.

Comment: Ok, got sorted out.
I had the original default server configuration.  It had the php section commented out.  
Once I uncommented that the php code was executed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the php files on /var/www/html/ , but you will need to install an Apache Server, it's easier if you use LAMP [How To Install LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Please include the appropriate parts of the link you included directly into your answer. Thanks

Comment: The OP uses `nginx` so there is no need for an `apache` server.

Answer (score -1):

use 
`sudo php -S localhost:portno` from command-line and open link in firefox or any browser